# Play Framework *.json template is not utf-8. why? and how can I set it to utf-8?

Tags: json, templates, utf-8, playframework

I'm working with the play framework, current version 1.2.4.

I want to have my own json structure and don't want to return the complete objects. So I decided to use json templates.

Easy example.

Controller:

```
Service service = Service.find("byIdAndCompany", new Long(serviceId), company).first();
    if (service != null) {
        render(service);
    }
```

So I get a full filled service object and return it.

My json-template is very very easy for testing purposes:

```
{
    "serviceName": "${service.name}"
}
```

that's it. but the Content-Type is only "application/json" and if I would return the whole service object with the play given renderJSON()-method it's correctly UTF-8 and the Content-Type is "application/json; charset=utf-8".

For germans with umlauts the umlauts are not correctly displayed and other special character.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your JSON template file encoding is set to `UTF-8`. (Refer to [Play Framework documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/i18n) for more information.)